# JQUERY alert on checked radio button without onclick

Tags: jquery

I dont want to use onclick. I am trying to properly use and if else statement for when the radio button is checked but I must be doing something wrong since even my simple test below is not working.

What is the solution for doing this right?

```
function test() {
if (jQuery("#vendor-date-method-checkbox").prop("checked")) {
alert('yes');
}else{
alert('no')
};
};   


<input type="radio" id="vendor-date-method-checkbox2" name="vendor-method-checkbox2" value="vendor-date-method-checkbox" autocomplete="off" disabled>
<label for="vendor-date-method-checkbox2">Date Method
</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="vendor-custom-method-checkbox2" name="vendor-method-checkbox2" value="vendor-custom-method-checkbox" autocomplete="off" disabled>
<label for="vendor-custom-method-checkbox2">Custom Input Method
</label>
<br>
<input type="date" id="deposit-due2" name="deposit-due" maxlength="2" size="4" class="deposit-input" autocomplete="off" placeholder="ie 'upon '" disabled>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call test.

```js
function test(event) {
  var target = event.target;

  if (target.checked) {
    alert('yes');
  } else {
    alert('no')
  };
};
//call your function
jQuery("#vendor-date-method-checkbox2").click(function(event) {
  test(event);
});
jQuery("#vendor-custom-method-checkbox2").click(function(event) {
  test(event);
});
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="vendor-date-method-checkbox2" name="vendor-method-checkbox2" value="vendor-date-method-checkbox" autocomplete="off">
<label for="vendor-date-method-checkbox2">Date Method
</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="vendor-custom-method-checkbox2" name="vendor-method-checkbox2" value="vendor-custom-method-checkbox" autocomplete="off">
<label for="vendor-custom-method-checkbox2">Custom Input Method
</label>
<br>
<input type="date" id="deposit-due2" name="deposit-due" maxlength="2" size="4" class="deposit-input" autocomplete="off" placeholder="ie 'upon '" disabled>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. On page load this now displays the 'yes' alert but as I toggle between the two radio buttons nothing happens and there are no more alerts?

Comment: your inputs are disabled. Remove the disabled attribute. Do you want me to add that to the code?

Comment: You mispelled your query.

Comment: @Manny I updated the code. That should work how you want it.